# <%= won't show wanted string on client side

Tags: asp.net, string, user-controls

I have this line of markup

```
<a id="cashout_btn" href="#" data-tooltiptext="<%=this.CashOutTooltip%>" runat="server">

        <span id="cashout_txt" class="cashout_txt" runat="server">        150</span> 

</a>
```

But on client side I see:

```
<a href="../Controls/NetworkPAU/#" id="networkPauControl_cashoutControl_cashout_btn"  

data-tooltiptext="&lt;%=this.CashOutTooltip%&gt;" 

data-tooltiptype="simpleTip"><span id="networkPauControl_cashoutControl_cashout_txt" class="cashout_txt">
            150</span> </a>
```

Meaning no string was populated in 
data-tooltiptext="<%=this.CashOutTooltip%>"

Any idea?

Comment: if this the only part that it does not replace the server code or in all entire page?

Comment: For some reason the '<' character gets XML encoded...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use such evaluations in server controls' markup.

Best solution would be do that in code-behind, for example, during Page.Load event, but instead of giving you a sample of that, I'd argue that using localization would be better for that case.

You can start learning more by following this link:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`<%= expressions` cannot be used as `properties`, you have to use `<%# expressions` instead.

Since `<%# expressions` are evaluated at `DataBind()` time, if you used that, then you need to call `DataBind();` method at PreRenderComplete like..

```
 protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:
a. using <%# instead of <%=
b. removing "this" in <%=this.CashOutTooltip%>
(Not sure why? Because "this" relates to the page and not the an instance of the class in the code behond ??)